# how to ask cmake to clean Release configuration for Msvc build

Tags: visual-c++, release, cmake

I have build tree for different compilers (msvc-2008, mingw-gcc), generated with CMake:

```
\---buildroot
    \---win32
        +---mingw-gcc-4.4.0
        |   +---Debug
        |   \---Release
        \---msvc-2008
            +---Debug_Dynamic
            +---Debug_Static
            +---Release_Dynamic
            \---Release_Static
```

And i want to build all configurations with one script. I wrote simple python wrapper, which iterates over hierarchy and calls **cmake --build**. For **msvc** builds i need to select proper configuration for building, cleaning and installing

I read documentation, and find parameter `--config`.

So **final** cmake command looks like:

```
cmake --build win32\mingw-gcc-4.4.0\Debug
cmake --build win32\mingw-gcc-4.4.0\Release
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Debug_Dynamic --config Debug
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Debug_Static --config Debug
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Release_Dynamic --config Release
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Release_Static --config Release
```

Here cmake commands for **clean** all targets:

```
cmake --build win32\mingw-gcc-4.4.0\Debug --target clean
cmake --build win32\mingw-gcc-4.4.0\Release --target clean
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Debug_Dynamic --config Debug --target clean
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Debug_Static --config Debug --target clean
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Release_Dynamic --config Release --target clean
cmake --build win32\msvc-2008\Release_Static --config Release --target clean
```

So i found answer on my question.

Comment: The question is not really clear. First of all, cmake does not accept those options on the command line. Second, if you already created the project (with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release) then why run cmake again?

Comment: @Andre, it is possible to build project with CMake, not only configuring. Our project compiles with different compilers, so `cmake --build` really helps.
It is possible to select configuration for building, just call 
`cmake --build my_build_dir --config Release --target clean`
will clean **Release** configuration, similar command for installing.

Comment: Are you sure, because I get an error, something like "source directory --build does not exist"

Comment: http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#opt:--builddir

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. But,... it still does not work for me. Because I do not know which underlying command-line build system is used by cmake I have created an answer for devenv and for msbuild. Perhaps you can edit your question and tell which one is used?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I must admit that I do not know much about the --build option for Cmake. However, cmake also generates a 'package' and 'install' target, perhaps you can specify those with the --target option with cmake --build.

```
cmake --build my_build_dir --target install
```

Otherwise, you will need to specify those using devenv or msbuild command line options. Without cmake this woule be something like

```
devenv INSTALL.vcproj /Build Release
devenv INSTALL.vcproj /Clean Release

msbuild INSTALL.vcproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
msbuild INSTALL.vcproj /t:Clean /p:Configuration=Release
```

I guess you can pass everything after msbuild/devenv through to cmake with '--'